# options[Text] is null or not an object in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am getting options[text] is null or not an object error. What i am trying to do here is i am checking what all multi select lookup column values are selected , comparing them with the value in an array and then removing them

```
  var responsibleselected = returntags("select","Responsibility selected values");
  for(var i=0;i<responsibleselected.options.length;i++)
  {
       if(responsibleselected.options[i].selected == true)
          {
           for(var j=0;j< ResponsibleArray.length;j++)
            {
 if(responsibleselected.options[i].text == ResponsibleArray[j])//throws error here
             {
       GipRemoveSelectedItems(ctl00_m_g_6ad915a8_68ea_4c76_b67a_ad1215320288_ff391_ctl00_ctl00_MultiLookupPicker_m); 
             }
            }
          }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `.text` you need [.textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.textContent):

```
if(responsibleselected.options[i].textContent == ResponsibleArray[j]){
                                  //   ^--------------here it is
```

Comment: .textContent is returning "undefined" . I tried with .innerText as well , but i am still facing the issue.

Comment: @user9167 `textContent` should work. Look [this](http://jsbin.com/iyinaz/edit#javascript,html) sample.